# Why has this exception started occurring - java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I am developing my first Java, MongoDB, Morphia application and cannot solve the following exception:-

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:74)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.readMappedField(Mapper.java:797)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDb(Mapper.java:250)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.Mapper.fromDBObject(Mapper.java:191)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.convertItem(MorphiaIterator.java:134)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.processItem(MorphiaIterator.java:146)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.MorphiaIterator.next(MorphiaIterator.java:117)
    at org.mongodb.morphia.query.QueryImpl.asList(QueryImpl.java:150)
    at test.DatabaseManagerTest.testListParent(DatabaseManagerTest.java:172)
```

My Tech Stack is as follows:-

```
Java 8 jdk1.8.0_112
Morphia 1.2.1
Mongo java driver 3.2.2
```

My Parent Entity class:-

```
@Entity("parent")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    @Indexed(options = @IndexOptions(unique = false))
    private Child child;

    private String comment;

    private Date updateTimestamp;

}
```

My Child entity:-

```
@Embedded
public class Child {

    private int value;
    private String name;
}
```

The JUNIT code that fails:-

```
final Datastore datastore = DatabaseManager.getDatastore();

final Query<Parent> query = datastore.createQuery(Parent.class);
final List<Parent> parents = query.asList(); <<<< EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE

for (Parent parent : parents) {
    Assert.assertNotNull(parent);
}
```

What mistake have I made in annotating my two entity classes?

I guess its related to the embedded Child class as the stack trace mentions `org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper`.

What I find strange is that I havent chnaged the Parent and/or Child class in anyway, and all my tests used to pass fine.

Today I re run my tests and they have started throwing this exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is the data stored in child field. You have some bad data. If I have to guess as I can't look at data you've a child field with data like

> "child" : "somestring"

This will explain why you'll receive that specifc type of class cast exception.

Comment: I believe you are correct. As I "proved" this by creating a new database and repopulating with new test data and it all works fine. Is there any way I can identify the corrupt data in my original database?

Comment: Not sure how you would idenitfy the corrupt data but as long you are saving and fetching through application you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. I think that mongo does not consider a string datatype as an object. If the data stored in mongo is of type string while the associated Java variable is typed as `Object` then the variable can not be cast and this exception is thrown.

In my case, the issue was that I placed an `ArrayList<String>` in an `Object` variable and that morphia inserted it into Mongo as a `String` (an `ArrayList` with a single value seems to be interpreted as a single string). The causes an exception which prevents the loading of the Java object.